# Kinetic Energy Split Up in Center of Mass coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

Suppose I have a hoop of mass m and radius R with a bead of mass M glued onto the hoop's rim. Let $\theta$ be angle between the vertical and the location of the bead. If I work with the center of mass coordinates then the kinetic energy splits up as :
$T = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}m_{i}V_{cm}\cdot V_{cm} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}m_{i}v'_{i}\cdot v'_{i}\\$
Here $V_{cm} = $ velocity of center of mass and $v'_{i}$ = velocity of the i-th particle with respect to the center of mass. The first sum is simple to calculate, and for the second sum, when i = "bead" the sum is easy to calculate. However, when i represents the differential mass elements of the hoop, what does the remainder of the second sum evaluate to? That is, what does $\frac{1}{2}\int_{hoop} v'_{i} \cdot v'_{i} $dm evaluate to? My guess it's something like $\frac{1}{2}I_{cm}\omega^2$ where I can find the moment of inertia about the center of mass of the system via parallel axis theorem, but I do not know what $\omega$ should be. Please let me know how to proceed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the center of mass not at the center of the hoop, the second term in your calculation would be very complex.   For the problem you cite, if we can assume the hoop is rolling across the floor,  just analyze the forces when the bead is at the top of the loop. If the, ω, is given for some other position,  stay in the fixed system and calculate the energies for the bead and the hoop separately.